# Made my own logger in angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular-services

I have written logger service but I have an error which I couldn't understand.

Here is a part of code:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {
    private _log: Function;

    constructor() {
        this._log   = console.log;

        this.blockDefaultConsoleMethods();
    }

    public log(...args) {
        this._log(args);
    }

    private blockDefaultConsoleMethods() {
        console.log = console.info = console.warn = console.error = () => null;
    }
}
```

An error:
**`TypeError: Illegal invocation`**

The main idea is to deprecate default console methods

Comment: where does the error appear in the code?

Comment: @toskv when I call some method

Comment: what line of code in your example?

Comment: and how are you calling the service? how are you injecting it?

Comment: I inject logger in bootstrap method and get them in constructor of component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking `console.log` like this directly doesn't work. You could try and invoke it like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {
    private _log: Function;

    constructor() {
        this._log   = console.log;

        this.blockDefaultConsoleMethods();
    }

    public log(...args) {
        Function.prototype.apply.call(this._log, console, args); // <--- change here
    }

    private blockDefaultConsoleMethods() {
        console.log = console.info = console.warn = console.error = () => null;
    }
}
```

---

> Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xXxKVUbPABPTVNLNwZxb?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: The console object is not exposed until the first time the developer tools are opened for a particular tab. And furthermore does the `console.log` expect a `this` object inside to access members of it's object, which you don't have with invoking it directly like you did. That's why you need to add context to it like you can do with the `Function.prototype.apply.call` (see the `console` argument).